# How to get rig of the error Fuction () does not exist in laravel 8x?

Tags: php, laravel-8

```
Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/login','LoginController@show_login_form')->name('login');
  Route::post('/login','LoginController@process_login')->name('login');
  Route::get('/register','LoginController@show_signup_form')->name('register');
  Route::post('/register','LoginController@process_signup');
  Route::post('/logout','LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

This is my route in laravel 8x, but it tells me that Fuction () does not exist. What can i do?

Comment: Are you maybe using a really old version of PHP that doesn't support anonymous functions?

Comment: `Fuction ()` (typo) does not appear anywhere in that code. Search your project, then name it correctly. What is the exact error message?

Comment: The error is tha Fuction() does not exist

Comment: Does it actually say `Fuction()` misspelled like that?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i am gona look for it